# UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate in UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have created a `UIView` with `UICollectionView`.

In the interface declaration of the `UIView` I have conformed to the `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocols:

```
 @interface TestOverview : UIView <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

But when I run the app, it crashes and i get this error:-

```
error: -[TestScreenViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
```

- Just to be clear the method `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection` is in the `UIView` (TestOverview), which was declared to be the delegate of the `UICollectionView`. So why does it expect to recieve it in the `UIViewController`(TestScreenViewController), which contains the `UIView` that contains the `UICollectionView`?

Comment: I guess you linked it wrong. Did you bind the delegate and datasource to the view in nib?

Comment: @tia I think I did. Look here: http://i39.tinypic.com/2prid7b.png

Comment: Seems like you are binding it to `TestScreenViewController` instead of to the `TestOverview`.

Comment: Yep, it's linked to the File's Owner. The File's Owner for the View is the View Controller. Which is right. You should use the view controller.

Comment: Well, as @frowing said, you are binding it to the controller. Rebind it by removing bindings in Outlets section and drag it to bind to `Test Overview` view instead.

Comment: @frowing But I want to separate the code. I do not want to have enormous controller class. I wanted to separate the functionality.

Comment: You are trying to fight the framework then, everything is set up like that for a reason. If you try to fight it while you learn, you are going to have a harder time. Go with it and you can optimize later.

Comment: I do not have time problem right now. I prefer to spend some time to understand how do you do it better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, it would be better if you used a view controller as the delegate of your `UICollectionView`. That's what they are there for. Second of all, not only you need to declare that `TestOverview` implements the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocols, but also you need to tell the `UICollectionView` instance who their delegate and data source respectively are. You can either do it in code like this:

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

Or in the Interface Builder, by binding the dataSource and delegate items to `TestOverview`.

Comment: Just move the protocols stuff to the view controller so the interface looks like this: `@interface TestScreenViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>` and you should be fine.

Comment: I do not want to have enormous controller class. I wanted to separate the functionality. How do I do that?

Comment: You need to make the containing controller the delegate for your UICollectionView as @frowing just said, its the way it works. Simply in good OOD the owner of the member controls its access. Not only to mention it will make your code near impossible to read if parts of implementations are in various files.

Comment: @Dev2rights Thank you. I understood that the containing controller should be the delegate for your UICollectionView. But I would like to incluse all the code that is relevant to the UICollectionView, in some other place, so the UIViewController, will not be inflated. How do I do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? You dont save anything as a separate object would have to be instantiated meaning you need to allocate 2 things on the stack instead of one causing more overhead. Not to mention that is not how your suposed to do it according to the documentation.

Comment: The UIViewController won't be inflated. It will do what it's meant to do: control how a view behaves. You don't need an intermediate object.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to user viewcontroller as collectionview delegate than a uiview.

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```